# Join two table and shows with null values

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

Table 1

```
   Col  |  Col2
--------+---------
  AA    |     CC
```

Table 2

```
   Col  |  Col2
--------+---------
  BB    |    CC
```

Result I need

```
   Col1  |  Col2    |   Col4
 --------+----------+---------
   AA    |     CC   |  null
   null  |     CC   |  BB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find any relation between two tables so, i would do :

```
select col as col1, col2, null as col4
from table1 t1
union all
select null, col2, col
from table2 t2;
```

Comment: @AaronDietz. . . Thanks.

Comment: Colum with CC VALUE has a relationship

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . I would remove the first sentence or rephrase it.  The OP just seems to want `union all`, regardless of any "relationship".